# Maintain separate backstack for each tab (implemented with fragments)

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, android-tabhost

I am working on FragmentsTabs, can anyone tell, how to maintain separate backstack for each tab...?Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you can not. The `backstack` is unique for every `Activity` in which your `fragments` run. So the only way, IMO, is to have more `Activity`.

Edit: see my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9598475/fragment-with-multiple-backstack)

Comment: Have you gone through FragmentTabs example..? When they add a tab they take fragment as argument, not the FragmentActivity. Because of which the problem is coming.

Comment: Yes I know, and actually I was not giving you a solution to your problem.

Comment: I am able to mantain separate backStack if I do it using TabActivity but that is deprecated in 4.0 unfortunately.

Comment: An ActivityGroup, where every activity manages its frgaments. But as you have already said it is deprecated

Comment: Is there a workaround? I need to make an Android application modeled on one iOS app, and thus need it to navigate the same.

Answer (score 6):

The latest support library includes nested fragments.  Nested fragments can be used to implement a separate backstack for each tab.

You will need to have one child fragment within each of the parent tab fragments, and add to the backstack using the child fragment and not the parent fragment.

You will also need to override OnBackPressed so that it pops the backstack of the currently active tab fragment, when necessary.

For example:

```
    public void onBackPressed()
    {
        if (!currentTabFragment.getChildFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate())
        {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
```