# What is the best way to manage BackStack in Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment-backstack

Hello i want to manage BackStack in fragment i have implemented a method but im not happy with it becuase if i switch to multiple fragments again and again ,then i want that backstack dont switch to the same fragment again and again and just goes to each fragments one time backward and in the last to the Home_Fragment and then exit

For Eg : if i switch from notification to profile and make it like a loop by pressing it again and again ,and when i start pressing back it also follows the same loop that i dont want ,i want that even user do a thing like this the back stack only goes to each fragment only once and at the last goes to the Home Fragment and exit

Just like a big app like instagram or pintrest

here is a code

```
private final BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener navigationItemSelectedListener =
            item -> {
                Fragment selectedFragment = null;
                switch (item.getItemId()) {
                    case R.id.nav_home:
                        selectedFragment = new Home_Fragment();
                        break;
                    case R.id.nav_following:
                        selectedFragment = new Following_Fragment();
                        break;
                    case R.id.nav_upload:
                        selectedFragment = new Upload_Fragment();
                        break;
                    case R.id.nav_notification:
                        selectedFragment = new Notification_Fragment();
                        break;
                    case R.id.nav_profile:
                        selectedFragment = new Profile_Fragment();
                        break;
                }
                assert selectedFragment != null;
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().addToBackStack(String.valueOf(selectedFragment)).replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                        selectedFragment).commit();
                return true;
            };
```

Comment: You might find it easier to use Navigation Component: https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-getting-started

Comment: I would say its rather easy now . [Follow this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70738164/4168607) . I'll add a Sample for this if i get time because i could not find any myself .

Answer (score 0):

I'm having difficulty understanding the question/problem, but if you want to avoid re-adding a fragment that is already added then you could check the stack before adding a new fragment is it is already there. This [article](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/fragmentmanager#finding) might be helpful.

Comment: For Eg : if i switch from notification to profile and make it like a loop by pressing it again and again ,and when i start pressing back it also follows the same loop that i dont want ,i want that even user do a thing like this the back stack only goes to each fragment only once and at the last goes to the Home Fragment and exit ,hope it will help you understand my question better and sorry

Answer (score 0):

use `popBackStackImmediate("your-tag",0)`
or `findFragmentByTag` in `fragmentManager` and replace it(be careful about adding to back stack again and again).

Comment: can you explain the code a liitle bit so i can try it